# WPF Stackpanel height not resizing when removing a usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a stackpanel in a grid row with the row height set to auto.

I add user controls at runtime and the height resizes fine, when removing the user controls the height does not reduce though. I have tried to clear the stackpanel children, remove them one by one and also implemented `IDisposable` in each user control but when the child count shows zero the height has not reduced.

Sample XAML below, any help would be welcomed please?

```
<Grid x:Name="TestGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Test Header" Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderTextBlock}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="ChildItems" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: how did you removed the usercontrol?

Comment: As I say, I have tried clear, removing one by one and also implementing I Disposable. I see I Disposable disposing being fired and the control is removed as the Stackpanel child count show zero after removing items but the height does not adjust. I have also called LayoutUpdate and still no difference in height.

Comment: can you try to change the child visibility to collapsed
and tell me if it effected your stackpanel size?

Comment: Making it collapsed makes the height zero, I then remove all children and then make it visible again and the height is incorrect (still showing the same height as before I removed the children)

Comment: Use ItemsContainer instead of the StackPanel. Using StackPanel that way in WPF is a strong code smell.

Comment: I was previously using a ItemsControl but had the same results

Comment: Try using a Grid instead of StackPanel.  Grid's handle this better.

Comment: Then you must be doing something nasty in your code behind. Refactor to MVVM and your problems will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `StackPanel` with a `Grid.`  Grids stretch and retract better than StackPanels.

Answer (score 1):

Instated of removing put `Visibility` to `Collapsed`